# Install rpm packages using file globbing with errors

Tags: centos, rpm

I found a `rpm` feature.  If you `rpm install *` and one of the packages fails to install then none of the remaining packages will be installed.

Does anyone know how to use rpm to install packages with file globbing and have rpm attempt to install all of the packages?

I found that `--force` works, yet I do not want to install over already installed packages.

I doing this because I need to install all of the packages in a directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that the failure is a result of a bad exit status from an rpm script (pre/post, etc)?

If you resolve that issue and want to re-install using the glob, you might want to try:

```
yum localinstall *
```

Yum is smart enough to skip already installed packages. It will, however, stop on failed installs just like rpm does. So you'll need to either solve whatever problem that is first, or pass **--skip-broken** to it.

Comment: Or you can pass `--skip-broken`.